# Get from <input> dynamic values of id= and value= and make them variables to use them in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have clockpicker (https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) as a tool to input time on my php page, which contains a lot of similar but unique  fields.

It works like this:

```
<?php while // ...extracting data from mysql

// and we have got a lot of "cards" (Their quantity is not constant and there can be from 30 to 100 cards), each one of them has unique card_numuber and card_time
echo <div id='card'> ;
echo <div id='$row['card_numuber']'> $row['card_numuber']</div> ;
echo <div class='input-group clockpicker-with-callbacks'><input id='$row['card_numuber']' type='text' class='form-control' value=".$row['card_time']."></div>;
echo </div> ;
?>
```

And this is my script I use to get data to variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        afterDone: function() {
        var card_time = ??? // here is I have no idea how to get the~ <input value=".$row['card_time']."> 
        var card_numuber = ??? // and here I've got no clue how to mage var from dynamic id='$row['card_numuber']' value

        console.log(card_numuber, card_time);
        $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
            card_numuber: card_numuber, card_time: card_time
        })

        }
    })
</script>
```

I need somehow to get the data... from html  and pass it to javascript...
So:

`card_time` IS `value=".$row['card_time']."`

`card_numuber` IS `id='$row['card_numuber']'`

How can I get this such a horrible task done? Please, help.

Comment: Note: Your code is putting the same ID on multiple elements (a div and an input). That's invalid. One way to work around this is to give them both prefixes.

Comment: No, $row['card_numuber'] and $row['card_time'] are bothe unique and dynamic.

Comment: Oh, you mean id= ... $row['card_numuber'] and in the <input> is the same $row['card_numuber']...

Comment: You have `<div id='$row['card_numuber']'>` and also `<input id='$row['card_numuber']'`. So that `div` and that `input` will have the same ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, looking at the source, that plugin doesn't pass the `afterDone` callback **anything** useful. So in order to know what input is related to it, we'll have to hook things up in a more verbose way:

```
// Normally, you'd avoid using `each` like this, but sadly this plugin calls
// its callbacks with NO context information
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').each(function() {
    var input = $(this).find("input")[0];
    $(this).clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        afterDone: function() {
            var card_time = input.value; // The current value of the input
            var card_numuber = input.id; // The input's ID

            console.log(card_numuber, card_time);
            $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
                card_numuber: card_numuber, card_time: card_time
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I couldn't get it work.... `var $this = $(this);` is the key to my problem. I got it. But... I have this in console `TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined`

Comment: @PhilippNesterov: Sorry, didn't notice you were calling a plugin method. I see you've linked the docs, let's take a quick look...

Comment: I've tried `var card_time = this.value;
var card_numuber = this.id;` and in console I have `undefined undefined`

Comment: @PhilippNesterov: Wow, the docs don't tell us anything useful, and looking at the source, it doesn't pass along **any** useful information to that callback. Blech, not a well-designed plugin. I've updated the answer to account for that.

Comment: @PhilippNesterov: ...and now I've fixed it, I missed that your class is on the `div`, not the input. You should see `var input = $(this).find("input")[0];` in the code above; if not, hit refresh.

Comment: Just wow. You save the day. Very big thank you. It's unbelievable! It worked just fine. Thanks again!